# Consistency of Watch position Phonegap

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

I have this code in my phonegap application

```js
var options = {timeout: 180000 };
navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccess, onError, options);
```

supposed to be, it will fire out ever 3 minutes but the problem is it's firing every 1 second or every 5 seconds. In short, there is no consistency in time interval. Is there other way to get the result in exact time interval? And if I run it in background mode, Is there a way to continue track the location using this interval. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Timeout simply sets the maximum time that's allowed to pass from a call to get the current position to the time it's returned. This does not affect how often it sends the current position but does fire onError when it can't get a position within your timeout (3 minutes in your case).

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_geolocation_geolocation.md.html#geolocationOptions

As for background mode, it is possible on Android and iPhone. On Android, this seems to be the default behavior. For iPhone, in Xcode go to Targets -> Info -> Right click to add row. Choose "Required Background Modes" click the + sign, and for the value choose "App registers for location updates."

Edit: if you're really set on checking the geo position every 3 minutes (and not as fast as the GPS responds), I suggest writing a function that uses setInterval() to call geolocation.getCurrentPosition instead of using watchPosition.

Comment: I'm very curious about this. I have seen a few folks claiming that all that is necessary to run getCurrentPosition in the background is changing one line in the .plist file. Is there anymore info on this or any other steps? I have the exact scenerio described in the answer. setInterval, getCurrentPosition, with an modifed .plist. Still no background GPS. Anymore info?